# How to display web folder index in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have several files in a public static folder `myapp.appspot.com/myfolder` in a GAE app and would like to see the folder index (content) when opening that URL instead of error 404.

I can access individual files in it, but cannot see the folder index.

app.yaml:

```
- url: /myfolder
  static_dir: myfolder
```

Maybe something extra to put in app.yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered in [How to list the files in a static directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477135/how-to-list-the-files-in-a-static-directory).

There's no built-in solution to browse static files in App Engine.  Someone did put up some sample code http://code.google.com/p/appfilesbrowser/ that you might be able to leverage.

Comment: Thank you, I spent lot of time trying to find a solution with "index" keyword :)